# Why does MEDIAN() OVER (PARTITION BY) return the same result as MAX()?

Tags: mariadb, max, median

Result of subquery is:

[image]

One column consisting of ID (the same value for every result) and a column I want to get MEDIAN value from.

When I call query:

```
SELECT AVG(diff), MIN(diff), MAX(diff), MEDIAN(diff) OVER (PARTITION BY id) FROM (subquery)
```

Median is exact same value as max.

I have like thousands of measurements, always worked like a charm. Made another ten, did not change a thing and somehow the result is wrong.

I made 10 measurements (10 ID's), once it got executed correctly, 9 others says MAX = MEDIAN.

I have tried to call it several times to no avail, result is the same. One measurement is fine, others are broken. Could large database be the problem (almost 4 milions rows)?

Comment: Images of results or data aren't very useful because we can't copy the text or create runnable examples from them. Instead post a small stand-alone example that reproduces the issue - *as text*. Preferably in the form of CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements. See also [mre].

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) also applies to sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the fact that you have an implicit `GROUP BY` in your query due to the use of aggregate functions (`AVG`, `MIN` and `MAX`). When you use a `GROUP BY` and have a non-aggregated column in the column list, MariaDB will choose a value from a random row (which typically turns out to be the first row) for the non-aggregated column. It then applies the window function to that 1 row, giving that value. You can work around this by either using a second subquery to perform the `MEDIAN` window function e.g.

```sql
SELECT AVG(diff), MIN(diff), MAX(diff), AVG(median) AS median
FROM (
  SELECT id, diff, MEDIAN(diff) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS median 
  FROM sub
) sub2
GROUP BY id
```

Or by using window functions for all the fields and then choosing 1 row from the result set e.g.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
       AVG(diff) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS avg,
       MIN(diff) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS min,
       MAX(diff) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS max, 
       MEDIAN(diff) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS median
FROM (subquery)
```

These queries will give the correct result of:

```
avg                 min     max     median
116.61666711171468  23.64   243.934 99.3125000000
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=aa354674d74bfb16b9ffeb8bfaa19825)

**Note** If your subquery can return data for more than one `id` value, you need to use the first query above to get the correct result.